# how does getServletContext get called without declaring an object of its class in Servlets

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

In servlets, how does getServletContext get called without declaring an object of its class? getServletContext does not have static in its declaration. Consider for an example- ServletContext context=getServletContext();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## tl;dr

The Servlet you wrote inherits the `getServletContext` method from its superclass `HttpServlet`, which in turn inherits the method from its superclass`GenericServlet`.

An object of the servlet class you write is automatically instantiated by your [web container](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_container) such as Apache Tomcat, Eclipse Jetty, etc. See [*Servlet Life Cycle*](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/servlet/5.0/jakarta-servlet-spec-5.0.html#servlet-life-cycle) in the Servlet specification.

## Your Servlet ➜ `HttpServlet` ➜ `GenericServlet`

The code:

```
ServletContext context = getServletContext() ;
```

… is short for:

```
ServletContext context = this.getServletContext() ;
```

The `this` is a reference to whatever object is running that code. In our case here, that object is your own servlet.

Your servlet at runtime is an instance of the class you wrote at development time, automatically instantiated by your web container. That class, the class you authored, is a subclass of [`HttpServlet`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/servlet/5.0/apidocs/jakarta/servlet/http/httpservlet). That superclass `HttpServlet` extends from its superclass [`GenericServlet`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/servlet/5.0/apidocs/jakarta/servlet/genericservlet).

That `GenericServlet` class carries the method [`getServletContext`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/servlet/5.0/apidocs/jakarta/servlet/genericservlet#getServletContext()). The subclass `HttpServlet` inherits that method. And so too does your own class, as a subclass of `HttpServlet`, inherit that method.

How do I know all this? By reading the Javadoc.

See the [*Jakarta Servlet* specification page](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/servlet/).

Comment: That specification describes the 'Servlet Life Cycle'    https://jakarta.ee/specifications/servlet/5.0/jakarta-servlet-spec-5.0.html#servlet-life-cycle    "The servlet container is responsible for loading and instantiating servlets" That is the object that the author was asking about.

Comment: @rickz That seems obvious, the most basic concept in writing servlets. But nevertheless, I added a mention along with your link to the spec. Thanks for the feedback.